# Why html constructed by jquery show different from the original html?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an html file, like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='jquery.js'></script>
    <style>
    .some_list li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#wrapper').append("<ul class='some_list'><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>")
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <ul class='some_list'>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>            
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

The result look like this:

```
a b
ab
```

The two `ul` all take the same css effect, but show differently.

Why this happened?

Comment: Read this article http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ is the sapce difference caused by the inline-block elements ... On the second markup added with js there is no space between items making null the space you see on the first

Answer (score 1):

display: inline-block; has a small bug, you can not let the two tags .li without space otherwise they will join.

Put a space between your li tags:

```
$(function() {
        $('#wrapper').append("<ul class='some_list'><li>a</li> <li>b</li><li>c</li></ul>")
    });
```

Here you can see a better example: [jsfiddle.net/ng67otm6](http://jsfiddle.net/ng67otm6/)

Comment: It is not a bug, it is a feature :p You might want to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that parser interprets newline as space.

So these are equivalent:

```
<ul class='some_list'><li>a</li> <li>b</li></ul>

$('#wrapper').append("<ul class='some_list'><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>");
```

**Output:** ab

These two are equivalent too:

```
<ul class='some_list'>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
</ul>

$('#wrapper').append("<ul class='some_list'>\n<li>a</li>\<li>b</li>\n</ul>");
```

**Output:** a b

Notice **\n** which means new line.